# How do I suppress all logging message in SailsJS/Waterline?

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I have the following, but am still seeing a ton of Waterline logging messages.

```
log: {
  level: 'silent',
}
```

Comment: Hi. What version of Sails are you using & are you applying this to the `config/log.js` file per [Sails.JS documentation on logging](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/logging)?

Answer (score 1):

There are several files to configure logs (in order of precedence) :

- config/log.js
- config/env/*.js
- config/local.js

Check what you have in these files.